# TypeScript definition of `target` in a decorator

Tags: typescript

I'm creating a TypeScript decorator that mutates a decorated class method in-place:

```
function someDecorator(
    target: any,
    propertyKey: PropertyKey,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor,
): void => {
    const input = target[propertyKey];

    if (typeof input !== 'function') {
        throw new TypeError('The decorated value must be a function');
    }

    //...
}
```

If we ignore the fact that `any` is being used on line 2, this code works perfectly. Now let's start paying attention.

The type of `target` should declare that any value is allowed as long as one of its properties has the key `propertyKey` and is a function.

The TypeScript documentation [uses `any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorator-composition) in all of its examples of decorators. Surely there's a better way to do this.

An improvement to this is suggested in a few other guides like [this one](https://codeburst.io/decorate-your-code-with-typescript-decorators-5be4a4ffecb4#e24e): `Object`. However, this is still too wide of a definition and its use is discouraged in the [Do's and Don'ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html) of TypeScript. The guide suggests the use of `object` instead but this still doesn't guarantee that `propertyKey` exists on `target`.

Theoretically, this is supposed to work:

```
function someDecorator<Key extends PropertyKey>(
    target: {
        [key: Key]: (...arguments_: Arguments) => ReturnValue;
        [key: PropertyKey]: unknown;
    },
    propertyKey: Key,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor,
): void => {
    const input = target[propertyKey];

    if (typeof input !== 'function') {
        throw new TypeError('The decorated value must be a function');
    }

    //...
}
```

But then I get this error on both line 3 and 4:

> An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'. *ts(1023)*

It appears to be related to [Microsoft/TypeScript#26797](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26797) and I'm not sure how to work around it.

Because of this error, I also get this one on line 9:

> Type 'Key' cannot be used to index type '{}'. *ts(2536)*

Is there any way to declare an object that must have a specific property and allow for anything else?

Comment: could you please share also decorated method or class? Also your code contains errors

Comment: The decorated method has an arbitrary number of arguments and an arbitrary return value. I'm not sure where or what the errors are.